# Need help on IDEs and hexadecimal

Tags: ide

I have an exam coming up, and I need to learn a bit more about IDEs (Integretated Development Error).

I have already looked on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), and used the Simple English feature, but I haven't really been helped by it, which is why I am here.

If you have any tips I'd appreciate it, because my exam is in 3 weeks. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I also need help on hexadecimal, which I have also seen on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), again not being helpful.

Comment: The most common use of the acronym "IDE" is "Integrated Development Environment". Hexadecimal is base 16 numbers, e.g., most of us use base 10, with the digits 0-9, and have a ones place, tens place, hundreds place: hex is the same, but 0-F (A=10, B=11, etc) and has a ones place, 16s place, 256s place. No different, just goes a bit higher. E.g., https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/base-what-a-practical-introduction-to-base-encoding--net-27590, https://betterexplained.com/articles/numbers-and-bases/

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you, I will look further into this.

Comment: Either way, the question would appear to be largely OT for SO, which is for programming problems, not general education.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks, I will bear that in mind.